# Generic type for expression is determined at runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this interface that two of my entities implement:

```
public interface IFilterable
{
    AnotherEntity AnotherEntity { get; }
}

public partial class Session : IFilterable
{
    //Body defined externally by EF auto-generated code
}

public partial class Camera : IFilterable
{
    //Body defined externally by EF auto-generated code
}
```

I also have a where clause that is shared between them for most of my data calls:

```
session => session.AnotherEntity.Started > DateTime.Now
```

This is not the actual expression, but this is more or less how it works.  To prevent myself from repeating this, I wrote this helper method:

```
private Expression<Func<TFilterable, bool>> GetFilterClause<TFilterable>(DateTime dateTime)
    where TFilterable : IFilterable
{
    return filterable => filterable.AnotherEntity.Started > dateTime;
}
```

So that I could re-use this expression on my data requests:

```
public List<ReturnEntity> GetReturnEntities(DateTime dateTime)
{
    var clause = GetFilterClause<Session>(dateTime);
    return Get(clause)
        //More query generation
}
```

The problem is that I get a runtime error:

> Unable to cast the type 'DataWarehouse.Session' to type 'DataWarehouse.Entities.IFilterable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

But it works just fine if I replace the `where TFilterable : IFilterable` clause with `where TFilterable : Session`.  I thought that generic type signatures were generated at compile time so there would be a definition for every implementation of `IFilterable` already.  It looks like this isn't the case though.  Is there any way around this or am I forced to create a filtration clause helper method for every entity?  Right now it's not too bad with 2 entities, but I can imagine needing this filter to be applied to 3 or more in the future and maintaining that many similar clauses would be a nightmare.

Comment: Your "generic" method doesn't specify any generic types, nor does the caller provide any.  It shouldn't compile for that reason.

Comment: The helper method you posted can't compile. It has no type argument. The call site you posted would only work with a generic method where the generic type could be inferred, but there's no argument that would allow that. If you want an answer here, you need to start with a good code example. One that is complete, concise, and which _compiles_ successfully. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, I copied it by hand.  I've updated the signature and invocation to match.

Comment: Does this need to be a generic at all?  Try this: private Expression<Func<IFilterable, bool>> GetFilterClause(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return (IFilterable filterable) => filterable.AnotherEntity.Started > dateTime;
        }

Comment: Yes, if you try to do it without generics you will run into a compile time issue when trying to resolve a concrete entity from it's interface type with the Get<T>() method.